# getting url using http post method in tcl 8.0

Tags: http, post, tcl

I'm trying to get some urls using post method in tcl 8.0.

it doesn't print any output.

here is chunk of my code.

```
foreach sKey [array names aQuery] {                                        
    set sValue $aQuery($sKey)                                              
    append sQueryString "[::http::formatQuery $sKey $sValue]&"                                  
}                                                                          

set sQueryString [string trim $sQueryString "&"]                           

set sToken [::http::geturl $sUrl -query $sQueryString -channel stdout] 

::http::wait $sToken                                                   

upvar #0 $sToken state                                                     

foreach sKey [array names state] {                                         
    puts "$sKey $state($sKey)"                                             
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade already. Why the heck are you using a version that was released in the last millenium.

The http::formatQuery procedure takes one or more key value pairs as arguments so that part would be better rendered as below. If in doubt its probably better to avoid using the -channel option and check for the status yourself. So something like:

```
set query [eval ::http::formatQuery [array get aQuery]]
set tok [http::geturl $sUrl -query $query -timeout 10000]
http::wait $tok
if {![string compare [http::status] "ok"]} {
    puts [http::data $tok]
} else {
    puts stderr [http::error $tok]
}
http::cleanup $tok
```

Note that in more recent versions of tcl you could have used `[http::status] eq "ok"` or `[string equal [http::status] "ok"]`. Don't forget to cleanup the http token. If you are doing this in a GUI program, use the -command option and do all the work in the callback so you don't freeze the UI while doing the http::wait.